# Uploading and downloading a 2 dimensional array using file_put_contents file_get_contents - php

Tags: php

Hopefully, I won't be a novice for long.  I have a 2-dimensional array (simplified) that I'm trying to work with.  Simply pulling out, adding to, and uploading a file record. Can somebody forgive my ignorance and explain what I'm doing wrong?:

```
<?php
// Updating Current Number of Vendors
$vendorcount = @file_get_contents('../Keys/VendorCount/$v');
if(isset($vendorcount))
{
$new_vendor_number = ($vendorcount + 1);
$n = $new_vendor_number;
}
else
{
$vendorcount = 0;
$new_vendor_number = 1;
$file = '../Keys/VendorCount/$v' ; 
file_put_contents($file, $vendorcount) ;
};

//getting record from file
$record = file_get_contents('../Vendors/$vendorlist');

//adding new information to record array
$record[$n] = array($new_vendor_number, $catname);

//uploading updated record
$file = '../Vendors/$vendorlist' ; 
file_put_contents($file, $record) ;
?>
```

Comment: We need more details here.  What does your array look like?  What's the problem here?  What does this code do/not do?

Comment: For test, try this: `$a = 'Test'; echo 'Variable a is $a'; echo "Variable a is $a";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in order to store an array to a file or restore it from a file. Like this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);

// writing to file
file_put_contents('file.txt', serialize($array));

// restoring from file
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

This will work with arrays of any dimension.

Comment: Perhaps my problem, in addition to not serializing, is in not properly defining my array.  Using the above example: $record = array(array($new_vendor_number, $catname));

Comment: Try it with my simple example and improve it step by step to your solution. Then you'll see which step in your code is wrong.